# python combine multiple sublist in to single list by group

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

How to combine these two sublist in to single sublist grouped by datetime?
Because in the two sublist common factor is timestamp.I hope someone can help me on this.

```
   [[('2017-08-08 10:00:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:05:38', 8.0), ('2017-08-08 10:10:38', 7.5), ('2017-08-08 10:15:38', 8.3), ('2017-08-08 10:20:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:25:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:30:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:35:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:40:38', 55.0), ('2017-08-08 10:45:38', 85.0), ('2017-08-08 10:50:38', 55.0), ('2017-08-08 10:55:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 11:00:38', 53.0)], 
    [('2017-08-08 10:00:38', 11.2), ('2017-08-08 10:05:38', 10.0), ('2017-08-08 10:10:38', 13.0), ('2017-08-08 10:15:38', 101.0), ('2017-08-08 10:25:38', 10.0), ('2017-08-08 10:30:38', 10.0), ('2017-08-08 10:35:38', 110.0), ('2017-08-08 10:45:38', 100.5), ('2017-08-08 10:50:38', 100.5), ('2017-08-08 10:55:38', 10.05), ('2017-08-08 11:00:38', 10.10)]]
```

**Desired Output:**
Example

a - Timestamp

```
[[a, x0,x1], [b, y0,y1], [c, z0,z1]]
```

**Update:**
Extremely sorry for changing the desired output format ,but this format will help me.Thanks

Comment: @JohnGalt Thanks for your response. I  have updated my question.If still not clear please let me know?

Comment: yes i am sure..

Comment: So if you have `[(a, x0), (b, y0), (c, z0)]` and `[(a, x1), (b, y1), (c, z1)]`, then your desired output is `[a, b, c, x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1]`? At least that's how I've understood your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = [
    [('2017-08-08 10:00:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:05:38', 8.0), ('2017-08-08 10:10:38', 7.5), ('2017-08-08 10:15:38', 8.3), ('2017-08-08 10:20:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:25:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:30:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:35:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 10:40:38', 55.0), ('2017-08-08 10:45:38', 85.0), ('2017-08-08 10:50:38', 55.0), ('2017-08-08 10:55:38', 5.0), ('2017-08-08 11:00:38', 53.0)],
    [('2017-08-08 10:00:38', 11.2), ('2017-08-08 10:05:38', 10.0), ('2017-08-08 10:10:38', 13.0), ('2017-08-08 10:15:38', 101.0), ('2017-08-08 10:25:38', 10.0), ('2017-08-08 10:30:38', 10.0), ('2017-08-08 10:35:38', 110.0), ('2017-08-08 10:45:38', 100.5), ('2017-08-08 10:50:38', 100.5), ('2017-08-08 10:55:38', 10.05), ('2017-08-08 11:00:38', 10.10)]
]

data_dicts = [dict(obj) for obj in data]
final_data = [
    [time_stamp]+[d.get(time_stamp) for d in data_dicts] for time_stamp in set().union(*data_dicts)
]
```

Comment: This works fine,but why  timestamp is not in ordered format?When i implement this code i am getting this result `from db
[('2017-08-17 12:56:59', 10.366465796627999), ('2017-08-17 12:57:48', 19.19), ('2017-08-17 12:58:51', 0.05)]
after data_dict
[{'2017-08-17 12:56:59': 10.366465796627999, '2017-08-17 12:58:51': 0.05, '2017-08-17 12:57:48': 19.19}]
`

Comment: the word `from db` and after `data_dict` just for your understanding..thanks

Comment: Try `OrderedDict` instead of `dict()`. It can be imported from `collections` module.

Comment: Yes i have tried OrderedDict. its works till data_dict then if i check final_data again order got changed. **data_dict**`[OrderedDict([('2017-08-17 12:56:59', 10.366465796627999), ('2017-08-17 12:57:48', 19.19), ('2017-08-17 12:58:51', 0.05)])]`
**final_data**
`[['2017-08-17 12:56:59', 10.366465796627999], ['2017-08-17 12:58:51', 0.05], ['2017-08-17 12:57:48', 19.19]]`

Comment: Just i now got solution! I have used `sorted(final_data)` works fine. thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following, just set x = [your list].

```
i = 0
list = []
while i < len(x):
  for j in x[i]:
    list.append(j[0])
  i += 1

i = 0
while i < len(x):
  for j in x[i]:
    list.append(j[1])
  i += 1

final = tuple(list)
```

RESPONSE TO COMMENT:

```
i = 0
list = []
list2 = []
list3 = []
while i < len(x[0]):
  list.append(x[0][i][0])
  list2.append(x[0][i][1])
  i += 1

j = 0
while j < len(x[1]):
  list.append(x[1][j][0])
  list3.append(x[1][j][1])
  j += 1

final = [list, list2, list3]
```

Comment: I added a response to the comment you left, think got deleted with the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.By mistake i have posted the wrong format,now i have updated it.Can it be possible?Any help on that?

Comment: I've solved two similar questions you've had. I think you should take a crack at this one on your own. Use my code as a start and try to work through it. Let me know if you get stuck. Good luck!